concise way to set the remote for a branch without having to type the branch name
Sometimes when I git pull I find that local branch main is not tracking remote origin/main:
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=<remote>/<branch> main

Is there a shorter command than this to make the current branch track its namesake on a remote? I don't want to have to copy-paste the name of the branch that I'm on or type it twice -- it's tedious.

My 2 cents.... there is a place holder for the current branch name: @. So: git push some-remote -u @. Then you can do git push.

By "sometimes", do you mean that this reoccurs randomly, even if you set it once?

Simple solution: don't say git pull.  Instead, say git fetch followed by git merge.

I've found that this works:
git push -u origin

But it's not terribly obvious!
It also possibly relies on there being no new commits on the remote?

Configure the default push branch using the following command: git config push.default simple.
Use --global to set it globally for all repositories.
This command will push the current branch to the remote branch that has an identical name.

You can use:
git push -u origin HEAD

This command will set the upstream branch for the current local branch to its namesake on the remote, named origin. Here, HEAD refers to the current branch you are on, so you don't need to explicitly type out the branch name. -u is the short option for --set-upstream-to
Below command will set the upstream branch of the current branch (main in your case) to <remote>/<branch>. If you're intending to set the upstream for the current branch, you would typically use HEAD instead of main if you're on main branch.
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> HEAD

To summarize:
git pull origin <branch>
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> HEAD
git push -u origin HEAD

Replace <branch> with the actual branch name you are working with. This sequence ensures that you first pull changes from the remote branch, set up tracking correctly, and then push your changes to the remote branch.
